# How do I count distinct values from same id?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I count distinct values from a column if there are some duplicates for each ID?

I've tried COUNT, DISTINCT, CASE and everything but I can't count distinct values for each ID. I have a table like this.

```
ID          Symptom
1           Headache
1           Headache
1           Hematuria
1           Leg pain
1           Headache
2           Cough
2           Headache
2           Cough
3           Cough
3           Cough
3           Cough
```

I want to obtain something like this.

```
ID    Symptom 
1     Headache
1     Hematuria
1     Leg pain
2     Cough
2     Headache
3     Cough
```

Or how do I obtain the total count? Like there are 5 distinct symtomps but not 11 symptoms (If I use DISTINCT I would obtain 4).

Comment: What did you try? Why didn't they work? You say you tried `DISTINCT`, but that looks exactly like what you need. What was the statement you wrote? I can't see how `DISTINCT` would return 4 rows for the values you've provided (perhaps because you just returned the value of `symptom`, but then if you want the ID, why didn't you return that?).

Answer (score 4):

You need `distinct` with `select` statement :

```
select distinct id, Symptom
from table t;
```

If you need unique count then use it inside `count()` :

```
select id, count(distinct Symptom)
from table t
group by id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just group by those fields :

```sql
SELECT ID, Symptom
FROM Symptoms
GROUP BY ID, Symptom
```

Fiddle : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/48dde/2/0

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, Symptom
FROM MY_TABLE
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: You can't use ordinal position in the `GROUP BY` clause (you're effectively saying group by the integer values `1` and `2`). Also, using ordinal values is normally a bad idea: [Bad habits to kick : ORDER BY ordinal](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal).

Comment: Plus, he isn't asking for an aggregate anyway. He only wants distinct combos.